# VBA - Function for Creating an n by m Matrix

Tags: excel, vba, matrix

I am currently working with arrays and loops, and am trying to write a function that will output an n by m array (a matrix) with the numbers {1, 2, 3, ... , n*m}

I am trying to learn some basic VBA code, this is purely for educational purposes.

This is what I have come up with:

```
Function createMatrix(n, m)    
Dim matrix(1 To n, 1 To m) As Integer    
x = 1    
For i = 1 To n
    For j = 1 To m        
        matrix(i, j) = x            
        x = (x + 1)            
    Next j
Next i   
createMatrix = matrix    
End Function
```

It returns `#VALUE`. I cannot understand why.

I got it to work at one point (creating a 3x3 matrix) by making it a function that did not take any variables and then initializing the matrix array by

```
Dim matrix(1 to 3, 1 to 3) As Integer
```

replacing `n` and `m` in the for loops with 3s.

So I guess the variables `n` and `m` are causing the problems, but don't know why.

Comment: You can use array declaration like you did ```Dim matrix(1 To ..., 1 To ...)``` only with constants, which means ```Dim matrix(1 To 3, 1 To 3)``` will work and the array will have three rows and three columns. But with variables ```n, m``` like (1 To n, 1 To m) you have to use ReDim which is shown in answers of @Jason Faulkner and @Leni Ohnesorge. One more thing, when you get ```#VALUE!``` error check the  separator of the parameters. The separator can be comma or semicolon. With comma enter formula in cell ```=createMatrix(3,3)``` mit semicolon ```=createMatrix(3;3)``` Shift + Ctrl + Enter.

Comment: the semi-colon is for delimiting rows in an array constant, but here the function is expecting integer arguments for *dimensioing* an array, not passing values *into* an array.

Answer (score 4):

Array declarations *must* be static (where the bounds are defined by a hardcoded value); however you can resize them dynamically using the `ReDim` statement.

```
' Declare an array.
' If you want to size it based on variables, do NOT define bounds.
Dim matrix() As Integer
' Resize dynamically.
ReDim maxtrix(n, m)
```

Note that when you `ReDim`, all values will be lost. If you had values in `matrix` that you wanted to keep, you can add the `Preserve` keyword:

```
ReDim Preserve matrix(n, m) ' Keep any existing values in their respective indexes.
```

Answer (score 3):

You first need to declare array as dynamic array and then redim it to your dimension.

```
Function createMatrix(n, m)
   Dim matrix() As Integer
   ReDim matrix(1 To n, 1 To m) As Integer
   x = 1

    For i = 1 To n
       For j = 1 To m
            matrix(i, j) = x
            x = (x + 1)
        Next j
    Next i

    createMatrix = matrix
End Function
```

Comment: You can omit the `Dim matrix() As Integer` statement, even with `Option Explicit` declared, as the `ReDim` statement is sufficient to declare *and* dimension the variable.